# GR - curve (in)completeness & (in)extendibility

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

Seeking clarification of the distinction between completeness of geodesics/extendibility of curves in GR spacetimes? (Confirm: not the *geodesic completeness of a spacetime* but the completeness of an individual geodesic.)

I think it's the use of the negative *in*extendible that may be confusing me.

I am happy with past/future inextendibility for a causal curve as being without a past/future endpoint as defined by Wald (*General Relativity*, 1984, p193) for a spacetime manifold $M$, paraphrased as,

> Let $\gamma$ be a causal curve, then $\gamma$ has a *future
>   endpoint* $p\in M$ if for every neighbourhood $O$ of $p$ there
>   exists a $t_{0}$ such that  $\gamma(t)\in O\  \forall t>t_{0}$, and
>   similarly for a *past endpoint*. [Because $M$ is Hausdorff it can have
>   at most one future and one past endpoint.]

Some specific cases:

Consider a causal geodesic $\lambda$ through the (arbitrary) origin of Minkowski space.

**Case 1 - Inextendible + Incomplete**
Remove the point $\vec{0}$ from $\lambda$; $\lambda$ is now in two geodesic pieces; the piece $\lambda(t), t>0$ is past inextendible and the piece $t<0$ is future inextendible (each is an open set and so has no endpoints).

With the Minkowski metric, both pieces seem incomplete, since the affine parameter does not span $(-\infty, \infty)$.

**Case 2 - Not Inextendible + Incomplete**
If, instead of a point, a closed interval on $\lambda$ is removed, both pieces are extendible (they have endpoints) but they also incomplete.

**Case 3 - Not Inextendible + Complete**
$M$ not Minkowski, but with a metric that "pushes $p$ off to infinite distance along the curve".

Inextendible = no endpoint, but as Wald says , "the endpoint need not lie on the curve, i.e., there need not exist a value of $t$ such that $\lambda(t) = p$." so if the affine parameter takes $\lambda$ arbitrarily close to $p$ as it tends to an $\infty$, the geodesic would be complete and not inextendible.

(But definitely $p\in M$ and not not one of those philosophically troublesome "missing points" :)

**Case 4 - Inextendible + Complete**
$M$ Minkowski without excisions, $\lambda$ is infinitely long in both directions: affine parameter spans $(-\infty,\infty)$ and there are no endpoints.

Have I got this right, and what's the picture for spacelike geodesic/curves?

Comment: What does it mean for a single geodesic to be complete?

Comment: IF I have understood correctly, per the detail in case 4, a geodesic is complete if and only if its affine parameter spans the interval (−∞,∞). The definition of an affine parameter means that given an affine paramater $\gamma$, $\gamma' = \alpha\gamma + \beta$ (where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $\in$ reals) is also an affine parameter, so the specific initial choice of $\gamma$ is immaterial.

Comment: and that's different from a geodesic being extensible to $(-\infty, \infty)$ how?

Comment: The negative term "inextendible" is preferred, I think; and, yes - a curve is inextendible (in a particular direction) if it has no endpoint that way, i.e. it is *extendible* if it *does* have an endpoint. I *think* the idea is that a curve with an endpoint could be joined to another curve having the same endpoint, but Wald's point that the endpoint need not lie on the curve also confuses me - I'm not sure it's a problem for such a joining (if that is what is meant) but I'm also not sure it isn't. This is why I wrote out all four possible combinations...